# Send data from Server to Android Database

Tags: android, sql-server, web-services, synchronization

I have an android app which receive data from web service and insert it to android's local database. This data flow is begun with a button in app's admin panel. I mean, an author login to admin panel in device and click the "Start Sync" button and device's database start to sync with SqlServer database.

**I want to do is** trigger this event from remote server. In other words, I want this process to begin as if someone clicks the "Start Sync" button, when I click the button in an web application. Let this web application is server and the devices are clients. I want this process to be triggered for all clients (broadcast).

How can I achieve this ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have the clients (app) register to your server as GCM clients. The server can then send a request to all registered clients to update. In your app, you will receive an intent. [Here's how to get started](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html).

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I had already made a research about it. Is it for only send messages to clients ? So I dont need to send message or notification. I want to fire the event in client. Can GCM do that ? You mean server should send a specific message and client should start sync if server send the message (with a basic if statement) ?

Comment: Correct. GCM provides the mechanism and transport. You no longer have to worry about whether a client has access, is turned on, etc. You just send a message -- the message would then tell the client to do the sync, or it could do anything else.

Answer (score 2):

Just a hint.

I also once wanted to implement a similar strategy to force updates on clients.
In the end I switched to the app and user deciding when to download the data.  (on startup and an alarmmanager which controlled a non persistent Service for daily updates).

A lot of developers forget the users, I've seen many applications with persistent services, and more undesirable behavior. Just because you can control users or program easy.

Otherwise [Google Cloud Messaging](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) is the way to go, as 323go mentioned